# SocketIO 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, python, apache, flask, socket.io

I'm pretty new to web-dev and have currently been struggling with a bug for multiple days that I honestly have no clue how to resolve/have no idea what could be causing it. At this point I've exhausted what I think could be causing the problem, so any insights would be greatly appreciated!

I am running an Apache webserver through the Flask Python framework. My client-side JS (app2.js) is as follows:

```
// set up basic variables for app
var socket;

$(document).ready(function() {
        socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port+'/main');


        console.log(document.domain);
        console.log("Document ready");
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {

          console.log("disconnecting...");

         });

 console.log("Simple logging");
});
```

Further I have reduced my .html page that loads the above script to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/app2.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

When I load my page, I will see the following printed in the Chrome console:

```
Document ready
Simple logging
GET https://DOMAIN/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1465632212131-2&sid=d4082f4636fd4d04a5dcc4b660ee5b2a 400 (BAD REQUEST)
disconnecting...
POST https://DOMAIN/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1465632212141-3&sid=d4082f4636fd4d04a5dcc4b660ee5b2a 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

I have no clue what the source of these malformed GET/POST requests are, but as a consequence of them, my page becomes non-functional. If I refresh the page, I sometimes won't get these errors. Other times, I refresh the page and still get the same error logs and then if I stay on the page long enough, I get more GET/POST errors of the same flavor and a "disconnecting" message sprinkled in.

It's the lack of reproducibility that is throwing me off, and I'm not sure what else to consider/how to go about fixing this. I've tried to reduce the client-side .html/.js files to the bare minimum to see what could be wrong and for some reason the code is still failing.  I would be happy to provide any additional information that would help pinpoint what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that your Apache proxy setup is incorrect. Try running w/o apache to see if that avoids the problem. I do not have Apache configuration examples in the official documentation because in my experience Apache does not work reliably as a proxy server for WebSocket. My recommendation is that you switch to nginx if you can.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using flask